# Headings for 13 months on Array

Tags: arrays, pascal

I was wondering if someone can assist me, why the headers of the below code is not creating them correctly for 13 months. I would like to add `Jan(LY)` `Feb(LY)`......until `Jan(TY)`.

Please see below Heading code only,

```
     //Headings
   J:=0;            
   for I:=12 downto 0 do
    begin
         J:=J+1;  
         Amonth:=IntToStr(J);                               
         If basemonth-12 <=0 then Harray[J]:=Basemonth-I+13;  
         If basemonth-12 > 0 then Harray[J]:=Basemonth-I;
         If Harray[J] >13 then Harray[J]:=Harray[J]-13;                                                           
         //showmessage(INTTOSTR(Harray[J]));                                       
    end;           
        Heading1:=Monthcalc(Harray[1]);
        Heading2:=Monthcalc(Harray[2]);
        Heading3:=Monthcalc(Harray[3]);
        Heading4:=Monthcalc(Harray[4]);
        Heading5:=Monthcalc(Harray[5]);
        Heading6:=Monthcalc(Harray[6]);
        Heading7:=Monthcalc(Harray[7]);
        Heading8:=Monthcalc(Harray[8]);
        Heading9:=Monthcalc(Harray[9]);
        Heading10:=Monthcalc(Harray[10]);
        Heading11:=Monthcalc(Harray[11]);
        Heading12:=Monthcalc(Harray[12]);
        Heading13:=Monthcalc(Harray[13]);            

// showmessage(DateToStr(startdate));
// showmessage(DateToStr(enddate));
// Showmassage('test');                                           
end;  

Function Monthcalc(Amonth:integer):String;                                                      
begin
      Monthname[1]:='Jan';
      Monthname[2]:='Feb';
      Monthname[3]:='Mar';
      Monthname[4]:='Apr';
      Monthname[5]:='May';
      Monthname[6]:='Jun';
      Monthname[7]:='Jul';
      Monthname[8]:='Aug';
      Monthname[9]:='Sep';
      Monthname[10]:='Oct';
      Monthname[11]:='Nov';
      Monthname[12]:='Dec';
      Monthname[13]:='LY';          
      Result:=Monthname[Amonth];                                                        

// showmessage(DateToStr(startdate));
// showmessage(DateToStr(enddate));
// Showmassage('test');                                           
end;
```

Comment: Please always add the language of the code. Is this Delphi?

Comment: Does your language really not have locale features to handle this kind of thing?

Comment: I am developing this code in Fast Reports using a DBISAM database, this code  is Pascal Script

Comment: Where is the declaration of `Monthname` array?

Comment: What is it that your code is doing that you don't want it to, OR what isn't it doing that you *do* want it to?  And, what do you mean by `TY`?

Comment: When I align the Headers, the months don't line up correctly.   See below declaration:            Monthname: array [1..20] of string;                                                                              
  Heading1,Heading2,Heading3,Heading4,Heading5,Heading6,
  Heading7,Heading8,Heading9,Heading10,Heading11,Heading12,Heading13 :String;

Comment: I need to display 13months array of months Jan 17 - Jan 18.

Comment: Sorry, I can't visualize what you mean by "the months don't line up correctly".  Could you maybe add a cropped screenshot to your q?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I first suggest that you change month name array to a constant:

```
const
  MonthNames: array[1..12] of string = ('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec');
```

Next I suggest some changes to avoid a hardcoded time span of 13 months, because as you are now experiencing, requirements do change and hardcoded stuff is always harder to change than variable stuff.

Declare a variable e.g. `MonthSpan: integer` to indicate how many months should be included (in the future a new requirement of alternative timespans of 3 months, 6 months etc are possible). Also replace all `Heading1, Heading2 ...` variables with a dynamic array, named `Headings`:

```
Monthspan: integer;
Headings: array of string;
```

For now I just initialize these at the beginning

```
Monthspan := 13;
SetLength(Headings, Monthspan);
```

You have already previously calculated `StartDate: TDate` so using that and the existing variable `M` we can now write a simple loop for getting the headings:

```
M := MonthOf(StartDate);
for i := 0 to MonthSpan-1 do
begin
  Headings[i] := MonthNames[(M + i) mod 12];
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Headings[i]);
end;
```

`MonthOf()` is a function in unit `System.DateUtils`.

The above replaces `Function MonthCalc()`, and all of your code below the `//Headings` comment. Elsewhere in your code, where you used e.g. `Heading1` you now use Headings[0] (dynamic arrays are always indexed from 0 up) etc.

I'm not sure what the purpose of `HArray[]` is, but it is not needed for the determination of the headings.

Comment: Hello Tom, Thank you for all the input. There seems to be so much current conflicting code and would require greater assistance inserting the code above in the correct areas and removing the conflicting code.Please

Comment: @Griphon I added a few sentences.

Comment: I am going to redo all the code for this report i just wanted to ask if there was an easier way of getting an array to work for 13 months.